# C# Open XML SDK 2.5 - make Shape uneditable, unresizeable and immovable

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a method `AddShape()` inside a **C# script** using the **OpenXML SDK 2.5**, which adds a *Shape* to my Presentation.

When I open the Presentation in Powerpoint I can move, edit the text and resize the Shape. I want to **"lock"** the Shape, so that these actions (Moving, Editing the text and resizing) *can not be done*.

In other words I want that these three things can not be done by the user once he has opened the presentation with Powerpoint:

1. Text Content of the Shape is not editable
2. The Shape can not be moved
3. Width and height of the hape can not be resized

Are there any ways to achieve this with **OpenXML SDK**?

If so which properties do I need to add to the Shape and so forth?

Answer (score 1):

I found a Solution to lock a shape:

You should append to NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties Drawing.ShapeLocks properties, like in this Example:

```
NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties = new NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties() ;
        D.ShapeLocks shapeLocks = new D.ShapeLocks() { NoMove = true, NoResize = true, NoTextEdit = true };
        nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties.Append(shapeLocks);
```